# Is there any way to move list of file from one folder to another in one drive programatically

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using Microsoft graph API to read file from one drive folder (ie: Unprocessed), after processing, move it to another folder (ie: Processed).
In this process, I need to move all processed file in a single request.

Currently, I am moving one file in a single request, and it is working fine.

Here is the sample code I am using:

```
public async Task<List<DriveItem>> MoveItemToFolder(string itempath, string destinationpath)
{
    List<DriveItem> items = new List<DriveItem>();
    string sourceId, destinationId;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itempath) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(destinationpath))
    {
        var sResult = this.graphClient
            .Drive
            .Root
            .ItemWithPath("/" + itempath)
            .Request()
            .GetAsync()
            .Result;

        sourceId = sResult.Id;

        var dResult = this.graphClient
            .Drive
            .Root
            .ItemWithPath("/" + destinationpath)
            .Request()
            .GetAsync()
            .Result;

        destinationId = dResult.Id;
        DriveItem fileOrFolder = await graphClient
            .Me
            .Drive
            .Items[sourceId]
            .Request()
            .UpdateAsync(new DriveItem
            {
                // The following example moves an item by
                // updating the item's ParentReference.Id property.
                ParentReference = new ItemReference
                {
                    Id = destinationId
                }
            });

        if (fileOrFolder != null)
        {
            // Get file or folder properties.
            items.Add(new DriveItem
            {
                Name = fileOrFolder.Name,
                    Id = fileOrFolder.Id,
            });
        }
        return items;
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

I want to pass it a list of files and destination and this should move all files to destination in a single request

Comment: There isn't an API that accepts a list of files. Is there some reason why you're not just iterating over your own list?

Comment: The reason behind not iterating over list is to reduce no of request to the server. There may be thousands of files to be moved, and program have to wait for each response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine up to 20 requests in one HTTP call using [JSON batching](http://Combine%20multiple%20requests%20in%20one%20HTTP%20call%20using%20JSON%20batching):

> JSON batching allows you to optimize your application by combining multiple requests into a single JSON object.

I know they're working to get [add batching support to the SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/pull/412), but since I'm not sure it is available yet, I'm reluctant to give a code sample (I'd likely miss something). In general, calling batch endpoint is pretty straightforward as it is:

```http
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "method": "PATCH",
      "url": "/me/drive/items/{sourceId-1}",
      "body": {
        "parentReference": {
          "id": "{destinationId}"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "method": "PATCH",
      "url": "/me/drive/items/{sourceId-2}",
      "body": {
        "parentReference": {
          "id": "{destinationId}"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "method": "PATCH",
      "url": "/me/drive/items/{sourceId-3}",
      "body": {
        "parentReference": {
          "id": "{destinationId}"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Dear Mr Marc, thanks for your suggestion can you please provide a sample code to implement JSON Batching in C# console application. I have no idea how to implement it in console app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the graph api form batching json you can use:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

Example json for different request will be like below:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/me/drive/root:/{file}:/content"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/me/planner/tasks"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/groups/{id}/events"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "url": "/me",
      "method": "PATCH",
      "body": {
        "city" : "Redmond"
      },
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Responses to the batched requests might appear in a different order. The id property can be used to correlate individual requests and responses.
Here is the sample response for the above request:

```
{
  "responses": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "status": 302,
      "headers": {
        "location": "https://b0mpua-by3301.files.1drv.com/y23vmagahszhxzlcvhasdhasghasodfi"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "status": 401,
      "body": {
        "error": {
          "code": "Forbidden",
          "message": "..."
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "status": 200,
      "body": {
        "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.plannerTask)",
        "value": []
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "status": 204,
      "body": null
    }
  ]
}
```

From c# you can simply use httpclient and post the json request.

**Request format**

Batch requests are always sent using POST to the /$batch endpoint.

A JSON batch request body consists of a single JSON object with one required property: requests. The requests property is an array of individual requests. For each individual request, the id, method, and url properties are required.

The id property functions primarily as a correlation value to associate individual responses with requests. This allows the server to process requests in the batch in the most efficient order.

The method and url properties are exactly what you would see at the start of any given HTTP request. The method is the HTTP method, and the URL is the resource URL the individual request would typically be sent to.

Individual requests can optionally also contain a headers property and a body property. Both of these properties are typically JSON objects, as shown in the previous example. In some cases, the body might be a base64 URL-encoded value rather than a JSON object - for example, when the body is an image. When a body is included with the request, the headers object must contain a value for Content-Type.

Alternatively , i would suggest you to use cloud event driven programming in these kind of scenario . You might do the following:

1) Create a queue for storing events  or commands

2) Push a command from your console app.

3) Process it from a webjob  or Azure function which will be asynchronous.

Hope it helps.